# Hadoop 2.6 installation on Mac, failed to start ResourceManager

Tags: macos, hadoop, installation

I'm trying to install Hadoop on Mac, following this [post.](http://amodernstory.com/2014/09/23/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-yosemite/#hadoop)

Everything looks fine, but in the end, I cannot start the `ResourceManager`.
i.e. after running `$jps`.

It is supposed to show something like below.

```
2507 ResourceManager   ---------this is missing (not started)

1712 SecondaryNameNode

1412 NameNode

1540 DataNode

2045 NodeManager

2858 Jps
```

Here is the error message I got:

```
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/logs/yarn-myUserName-resourcemanager-Mac.out
```

**nohup: can't detach from console: No such file or directory**

FYI， I've also changed the ownership of this hadoop folder. (as follows)

```
$mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode 

$mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/hadoop_data/hdfs/datanode 

$sudo chown -R Tiger /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For wired reasons,  After posting this question. In less than 3 minutes, I retry to start the resourcemanager, it works.

Answer (score 0):

that's wired,  I just retried to start the resourcemanager, it works !!!!    thought the nodemanager stoped.     sorry for bothering, Omigo